Retrieving data from server after it's finished being processed
As the title states, I am trying to retrieve data from my server after it has finished being processed. More specifically, I am trying to get the processed data to my front end.
Background: A document is uploaded to google cloud, data is extracted from the document and stored in firestore, and then that extracted data is then sent back to the client through a GCP workflows POST function. The API endpoint below is able to receive my data. However, the response, if the method is a post, is sent back to the GCP workflow if data is received in the API route, and not sent to the front end. My below attempt at a solution was to have the data be stored on the client temporarily, and then front end would call this API route, and retrieve that data. An additional issue I am encountering is, because the processing of the document can vary depending on time, if I just immediately call the API route, it would just return null. Is there a way to sit and wait inside of the API route for data to appear in the API route?
let data = null

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const data = req.body.data

      console.log(data)
      return res.status(200).json({ success: true })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error trying to receive data from workflow: ${error}`)
      return res.status(400).json({ error: error })
    }
  }

  if (method === 'GET') {
    try {
      return res.status(200).json({ data })
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(`Error trying to send data from workflow: ${error}`)
      return res.status(500).json({ error: error })
    }
  }
}


Are you getting null? Because when browser hits the endpoint (which is usually GET), you're basically taking the let data = null as you've specified. You need to store the data somewhere, eg. Database or server-side local files and when browser hits the GET endpoint, it will fetch the let data = getDataFromSomewhere() then return the response. Otherwise you'll keep having the data = null on the front-end every time.

I guess the issue then is timing. Because the processing of the data can take various amounts of time, like 30 to 40 seconds. So if I call the api endpoint, as soon as I submit the document, wouldn’t it just return null no matter what? So I’d have to find a way to wait inside the endpoint for the data from the server?

Then call the API inside your NextJS API endpoint and return within it? You know POST can return data as well, right? So, call the api, keep async-await and then return res.json(data). Or maybe I just need more of your info.

@Sowmoo0509 Yeah I think there's some confusion. I know how to call and retrieve data properly within an API route. I'll add some more details to my question, as it's a lot to help explain
